# How do I stop Admob from causing fatal crashes?

Tags: android, admob

I've got an Android game that uses Admob for advertising. I use Google Analytics for exception reporting and my crashes happen almost exclusively in Admob related threads. I had a huge spike on 1st July which I guess they fixed fairly quickly as the crashes had disappeared again by 3rd. There were no updates to my game in this time.

Is there a way for me to prevent admob from crashing the game when Admob has a problem by somehow handling the exception in the admob thread? It's frustrating that I've got a 3rd party introducing bugs.

Comment: Don't use it? Adverts are annoying at the best of times.

Comment: @GrahamSmith Maybe Google should shut itself down as a company? All of those pesky adverts are clearly more hassle than they're worth to users.